# plpgsql function returns table(..)

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to get this plpgsql function to work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION outofdate(actualdate varchar) 
RETURNS TABLE(designacion varchar(255),timebeingrotten varchar(255))
AS $BODY$

 SELECT designacao, actualdate - prazo
 FROM alimento
 WHERE prazo < actualdate;
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' volatile;

SELECT *
From outofdate('12/12/2012');
```

It keeps giving me an error on line 2 - table ..

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near
>   "TABLE" LINE 2: RETURNS
>   TABLE(designacion
>   varchar(255),timebeingrotten varch...
>                   ^
>
> *** *Error* *****
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "TABLE"
>   SQL state: 42601 Character: 67

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I am not sure, but maybe you use a older version of pg without support of `RETURNS TABLE` syntax. Next problem in your example is wrong syntax for PL/pgSQL language - look to manual for syntax - every function must contain a block with `BEGIN ... END`. Records can be returned via `RETURN QUERY` statement. Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.pgsql.cz/index.php/PL/pgSQL_%28en%29).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(a int)
RETURNS TABLE(b int, c int) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT i, i+1 FROM generate_series(1, a) g(i);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM foo(10);
```