# Update table being returned in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking for help with a PostgreSQL function that returns a table.
I would like to know if there is a way of updating the table that is being returned.

Here's an example,

```
create or replace function fn_function()
return table(column01 integer, column02 integer, column03 boolean) as $$
    return query
    select col1, col2, false
    from tableXYZ;


    /* how can i update the table, let's say column03 before the function exits */

end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Can i give an alias to the table being returned?

The postgre version in use is 9.0.8.

Thx in advance.

Comment: I think that this may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279876/plpgsql-function-returns-table

Comment: @Cipous It didn't. But thx anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a set based solution.

The RETURNS TABLE is just portal to get data out you can't do anything inside the function that defines it. You could create another function and call this one and do things to the result set. However I use a temp table so you can manipulate the data before you send it out.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_function()
    RETURNS TABLE(column01 integer, column02 integer, column03 boolean) AS $$
    BEGIN

      CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_tableXYZ (column01 integer, column02 integer, column03 boolean) ON COMMIT DROP;

     INSERT INTO temp_tableXYZ (column01, column02, column03)
     SELECT col1,col2,col3
     FROM tableXYZ;
     --WHERE filter if you can.

      UPDATE temp_tableXYZ
      SET col1 = 9999;

      RETURN QUERY select column01, column02, column03 from temp_tableXYZ;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You can call it using an alias like this:

```
SELECT * FROM fn_function() as my_table;
```

Comment: I don't understand how your answer could help me. In my example i'm trying to update column03. Let's say its based on the results being returned.
I'm kind of new to PostgreSQL. I used to program in T-SQL. There i could have a function that returns a variable of type "table" and i could do inserts, updates or deletes to it. In Postgre, i see this is not so linear.

Comment: I see you want to not modify the data in the actual table just the data flowing out.  In that case I might inside your function select the data you plan on returning into a temp table alter the data in the temp table and in your RETURN QUERY select from the temp table.  I don't believe you can modify columns you referenced in RETURNS TABLE(column01 integer, column02 integer, column03 boolean).

Comment: I thought in having a temporary table, but wouldn't i have concurrency issues with that approach?

Comment: In what way?  The temp table is isolated to your session no one else can use it.

Comment: The results provided by the function are returned to a silverlight app. If two or more users on different machines are requesting the data wouldn't the results be mixed up ?

Comment: No more than two transactions that start at different times. A selects at 1:00PM and B selects at 1:02PM the data may be the same or different depending on what happened between. They each will see a snapshot of the database at the time they started.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a query which returns the values you want. It can be plain sql:

```
create or replace function fn_function()
returns table (
    column01 integer, column02 integer, column03 boolean
) as $$

    select col1, col2, col2 > 10
    from tableXYZ;

$$ language sql;
```

In the example above column 3 will be true if col2 > 10 and false otherwise. Another example using a subselect:

```
create or replace function fn_function()
returns table (
    column01 integer, column02 integer, column03 boolean
) as $$

    select col1, col2, (select max(col1) > 10 from t where col2 = tableXYZ.col1)
    from tableXYZ;

$$ language sql;
```

Notice that it is not `return` but `returns`

Comment: To fit this specific need, i think with the subselect approach you mentioned would turn out to be sufficient. But i would like to see more versatility in Postgre functions returning tables. BTW, what's the difference between using `return` and `returns` ? thx.

Comment: @Hugo `return table` is a syntax error. For more flexibility use a loop as in Igor's answer.

Answer (score 0):

To select from table, modify the results of select and pass them as results of a function try something like:

```
create or replace function fn_function()
returns table (
    column01 integer, column02 integer, column03 boolean
) as $$
begin
    for rec in select col1, col2, false as col3
               from tableXYZ;
    loop
      rec.col3 := col1 > col2;

      return next rec;
    end loop;
    return; 
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Details [`here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html).

To select get the results of this function simply

```
SELECT function_alias.col1, function_alias.col2 
FROM fn_function() function_alias;
```

You can do with this function same things you can do with normal tables.

Comment: With code provided i get a **Missing "LOOP" at  end of SQL expression**. I guess its the semicolon before the word loop. But when i remove that a get an error of rec must be a row variable. If i add a `declare rec tablexyz%rowtype;` i get another error saying **RETURN NEXT cannot have a parameter in function with OUT parameters**. thx.

Comment: I would highly recommend using an approach that doesn't do looping, but is set based.  In the small chance you can't do set based fall back to looping.  I don't see solving this problem requiring a loop.