# How to declare returning type for function, returning unnamed table

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

I want to create a function, that returns a table with 2 columns:

```
i   integer    -- or bigint?
arr integer[]  -- array of integer
```

What should I write instead of `???` in this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
RETURNS ???
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY (
        SELECT i, (ARRAY[11,22,33])[i]
        FROM generate_series(
            1,
            array_upper(ARRAY[11,22,33],1)
        ) i
    );
END;
$$;
```

Comment: `RETURNS TABLE`. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html

Answer (score 0):

see the answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279876/plpgsql-function-returns-table) question,
example of function return table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(a int)
RETURNS TABLE(b int, c int) AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT i, i+1 FROM generate_series(1, a) g(i);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need plpgsql for this. A simple SQL function would do the job:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(_arr anyarray)
RETURNS TABLE (idx int, elem anyelement)
$func$
SELECT i, _arr[i] FROM generate_subscripts(_arr, 1) i
$func$    LANGUAGE sql AS
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM test(ARRAY[11,22,33]::int[]);  -- Cast to declare type for literals
```

- The polymorphic parameter `anyarray` works for arrays of *any* base type.
  [How to write a function that returns text or integer values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587735/how-to-write-a-function-that-returns-text-or-integer-values/17605114#17605114)
- Use [generate_subscripts()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) to simplify the task.
- More about returning from a function:
  [How to return result of a SELECT inside a function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945932/how-to-return-result-of-a-select-inside-a-function-in-postgresql/7945958#7945958)

#### Postgres 9.4

There is a shiny new trick in upcoming Postgres 9.4: `WITH ORDINALITY`. Details in this related answer:
[PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Simplify to (no additional function):

```
SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY[11,22,33]::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY AS x (elem, idx)
```