# Postgresql function to return numer of updates made

Tags: postgresql

I have a set of 3 tables, each table contains 3 columns as following (user_id, user_name, user_lastname, user_code_type).

I am using below function to insert values from table 2 into tables 1 and 3.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "TestDB"."TEST_UPDATE_1"()
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
update1 integer;
update2 integer;
BEGIN
INSERT INTO "TestDB"."TEST.TABLE.1" (user_id, user_name, user_lastname, user_code_type)
SELECT RT1.user_id, RT1.user_name, RT1.user_lastname, RT1.user_code_type FROM "TestDB"."TEST.TABLE.2" RT1
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "TestDB"."TEST.TABLE.1" RT2 WHERE RT2.user_id = RT1.user_id);
GET DIAGNOSTICS update1 = ROW_COUNT;
INSERT INTO "TestDB"."TEST.TABLE.3" (user_id, user_name, user_lastname, user_code_type)
SELECT RT1.user_id, RT1.user_name, RT1.user_lastname, RT1.user_code_type FROM "TestDB"."TEST.TABLE.2" RT1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "TestDB"."TEST.TABLE.3" RT2 WHERE RT2.user_id = RT1.user_id);
GET DIAGNOSTICS update2 = ROW_COUNT;
RETURN update1+update2;
END;
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

As a result of the above at the moment i am getting total number of rows, which were inserted in both table 1 and 3.

What i am interested in as an output is a table which would indicate number of rows, successfully inserted into 1 and 3 (a single row and 2 column table with output results).

I've went through the number of post here but could not find the one that would link solution for this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change return type of the function:

```
DROP FUNCTION "TestDB"."TEST_UPDATE_1"();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "TestDB"."TEST_UPDATE_1"()
  RETURNS TABLE (count1 int, count2 int)
AS
...
```

and return query:

```
...
RETURN QUERY SELECT update1, update2;
...
```

Executing the function:

```
SELECT * FROM "TestDB"."TEST_UPDATE_1"();
```

More information you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4290462/1995738).

Comment: Thanks a lot for prompt response. I'll implement the change and post an update on results.