# why does it take so long to query in a postgres function with input variables

Tags: postgresql, cursor, plpgsql

I wrote a stored procedure in Postgres which takes two integer parameters as input.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.tickets_long_open(comp_id integer, days integer, ref refcursor)
    RETURNS refcursor
AS $$

begin
  open ref for 
  select q.svc_ord_nbr, q.po_nbr, q.state, q.city, q.cust_name, q.days_open, q.status
from 
  (select a.svc_ord_nbr, a.po_nbr, a.create_dtm,
        b.sap_sls_org_name, b.cust_lvl_2_name,
        d.close_dtm, d.debit_memo_dtm,
        l.state, l.city, l.cust_name,
        date_part('day', (select case when d.close_dtm is null then now() else d.close_dtm end close_ts) - a.create_dtm) as days_open,
        case when d.close_dtm is null and d.debit_memo_dtm is null then 'OPEN' else 'CLOSED' end status
    from dmt_mas_svc_ord_fact a
    inner join dmt_mas_cust_dim b on a.shipto_cust_id = b.cust_id
    inner join dmt_mas_svc_ord_degen_dim d on a.svc_ord_id = d.svc_ord_id
    inner join store_location l on b.cust_name = l.cust_name
    where b.sap_sls_org_name like '%US%'
        and a.create_dtm >= now() - interval '12 months'
        and l.company_id = comp_id) q
    where q.days_open > days
    order by q.state, q.city, q.cust_name;
  return ref;
end;

$$ language plpgsql;
```

In order to display the result set, I include cursor as the third parameter so I can run the following to fetch the cursor:

```
begin;
select tickets_long_open(1, 30, 'refc');
fetch all in "refc";
```

It took 26 minutes to return 88 rows of records.

If I remove the first two parameters `comp_id` and `days` and hard code them in query. The fetch only takes 19 seconds for `select tickets_long_open('refc')`. Everything else is the same.

Why does it take this long to fetch the result set when I have the two parameters? And why removing the parameters suddenly made it so much quicker?

**EDIT**:
After some debugging, it turns out the query is only slow only when it takes input variables at run time. Returning it as table does not change anything. Changing function to plain sql does not help either

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.tickets_long_open(comp_id integer, days double precision)
    RETURNS TABLE(svc_ord_nbr text, po_nbr text, state text, city text, cust_name text, days_open double precision, status text) 
AS $$
  select q.svc_ord_nbr, q.po_nbr, q.state, q.city, q.cust_name, q.days_open, q.status
from 
  (select a.svc_ord_nbr, a.po_nbr, a.create_dtm,
        b.sap_sls_org_name, b.cust_lvl_2_name,
        d.close_dtm, d.debit_memo_dtm,
        l.state, l.city, l.cust_name,
        date_part('day', (select case when d.close_dtm is null then now() else d.close_dtm end close_ts) - a.create_dtm) as days_open,
        case when d.close_dtm is null and d.debit_memo_dtm is null then 'OPEN' else 'CLOSED' end status
    from dmt_mas_svc_ord_fact a
    inner join dmt_mas_cust_dim b on a.shipto_cust_id = b.cust_id
    inner join dmt_mas_svc_ord_degen_dim d on a.svc_ord_id = d.svc_ord_id
    inner join store_location l on b.cust_name = l.cust_name
    where b.sap_sls_org_name like '%US%'
        and a.create_dtm >= now() - interval '12 months'
        and l.company_id = comp_id) q
    where q.days_open > days
    order by q.state, q.city, q.cust_name;
end;

$$ language sql stable;
```

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: If you run the query without the store proc also take 26 minutes? The most probale scenario is you dont have index for your tables and those are really big.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it takes a few seconds to run the query itself

Comment: doesnt make sense, but why you return a cursor anyway if only want display the results?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza eventually, I will call the function in python. But just wanted to see if it works. What else would you suggest to display the results as a function by providing parameters?

Comment: you can always return a table. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279876/plpgsql-function-returns-table . but if you use hard code parameters and doesnt work then is something else I dont know :(

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza is it better practice to return a table instead of cursor?

Comment: Depend on your requirement. With the cursor you need keep the connection open. With the table you dont.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the returned table is a temp table which does not exist after the commit, right?

Comment: correct, is just a data set

Comment: For this you neither need PL/pgSQL nor a cursor. Just put that into a plain SQL function.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what exactly is a `plain SQL function`? How is it different from the function in my post? Does it take input parameters and return result records?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name changed it to plain sql function. still the same

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza returning results as table does not seem to help

Comment: try to use FOR IN EXECUTE command. What PostgreSQL do you use?

Comment: @PavelStehule what is the benefit of using `FOR IN EXECUTE` as opposed to just `EXECUTE`? I am using Postgres 9.6.2 on Amazon RDS

Comment: Dynamic SQL uses one shot execution plans - so it can decrease a risk of bad blind optimization (with cost of creating execution plan every time).